# pastespecial of object shapes failed vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code to copy charts from an Excel 2010 worksheet into powerpoint. It loops through searches for all charts on the active worksheet then copy and pastes a link into powerpoint. There is also a small snippet of code that takes the chart title and puts it as a title into PowerPoint.

It works perfectly for me in most instances, however it is giving me a runtime error -2147467259 (80004005) Method 'PasteSpecial' of object 'Shapes' failed after 9 charts have been moved into powerpoint.  What could be causing this failure in the middle of running perfectly?

```
Sub CreatePowerPoint()

 'Add a reference to the Microsoft PowerPoint Library by:

    Dim newPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim activeSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim cht As Excel.ChartObject

 'Look for existing instance
    On Error Resume Next
    Set newPowerPoint = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

'Let's create a new PowerPoint
    If newPowerPoint Is Nothing Then
        Set newPowerPoint = New PowerPoint.Application
    End If
'Make a presentation in PowerPoint
    If newPowerPoint.Presentations.Count = 0 Then
        newPowerPoint.Presentations.Add
    End If

'Show the PowerPoint
    newPowerPoint.Visible = True

'Loop through each chart in the Excel worksheet and paste them into the PowerPoint
    For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

    'Add a new slide where we will paste the chart
        newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutText
        newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        Set activeSlide = newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)

    'Copy the chart and paste it into the PowerPoint
        cht.Select
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
        activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(Link:=True).Select

    'Set the title of the slide the same as the title of the chart
        If ActiveChart.HasTitle = True Then
            activeSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text
        Else
            activeSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Add Title"
        End If
    'Adjust the positioning of the Chart on Powerpoint Slide
        newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 0.5 * 72
        newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 1.75 * 72
        newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 5.5 * 72
        newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 8.92 * 72

       Next

AppActivate ("Microsoft PowerPoint")
Set activeSlide = Nothing
Set newPowerPoint = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: After you paste, try `Application.CutCopyMode = False` to clear the clipboard maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is very simple. You are not giving the Excel enough time to copy the chart to the clipboard.

Try this

```
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    DoEvents
    activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(Link:=True).Select
```

Comment: This solved it. Slows the process down significantly but is still far more efficient than me doing it by hand

Comment: It will slow the process down as excel needs time to copy things to clipboard depending on the size of what you are copying :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as well, It worked for me, if not increase the seconds and see (not it is 1 sec, For me it worked for 2 secs.)  Thanks, Syed.

```
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
activeSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(Link:=True).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Excellent! What would I do without Stackoverflow?

With Sheets("Step 2- GEs Eliminated") 'paste into the Step2 sheet
     .Cells(2, i * 4).Select
      Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:001") 'this line from Stackoverflow. 
      ActiveSheet.Paste
End With