# Excel charts pastespecial format

Tags: excel, vba, charts

Excel offers the possibility to paste a chart format to another chart (in a chart sheet) through the PasteSpecial.

Recording the procedure as a macro gives the following code:

```
Sub Macro4()
   ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
   ActiveChart.PasteSpecial Format:=2
End Sub
```

Trying to run it fails (method not found).

I am referring here to the chart sheet and not the embedded chart.

Please advise.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19186580/2224701. Also your method is missing the Copy command.

Comment: The post refers to pasting a chart and not its format. I don't need the Copy command as the source chart is already in he clipboard. It looks as ActiveChart has not a PasteSpecial method....