# VBA code for PowerPoint 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to take a table from Excel and copy and paste into a PowerPoint Presentation, but it needs to work with PowerPoint 2010.

This is what I have:
Sub CreateNewPresentation()

```
Dim ppApp As Object
Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set ppApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

ppApp.Visible = True
ppApp.Activate

Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Add

'Insert Table --- slide 1
Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)
ppSlide.Select

'Selects data for the Table to be copied
Worksheets("Select Bond Sectors").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(27, 11)).Copy
ppSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
ppSlide.Shapes(1).Width = _
    4 * (ppPres.PageSetup.SlideWidth / 5)
ppSlide.Shapes(1).Height = _
    4 * (ppPres.PageSetup.SlideHeight / 5)
ppSlide.Shapes(1).Left = _
    (ppPres.PageSetup.SlideWidth / 10)
ppSlide.Shapes(1).Top = _
    (ppPres.PageSetup.SlideHeight / 10)
'End of Selects data for the Table to be copied

End Sub
```

Comment: It won't work simultaneously on 2013 and 2010 versions since the methods to call are different. If I'm guessing correctly, you're having problems with the line `ppSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select` since that method wasn't called like that in 2010 versions

Comment: how could I change that so it does work in 2010?

Comment: [This might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186146/pastespecial-of-object-shapes-failed-vba)